# SQL String Utilities DLL Create Aggregate function

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a concat aggregate function via the steps provided by Microsoft here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182741.aspx

The trouble I'm having is that I can't find the StringUtilities.dll anywhere on my filesystem.

Where can I find this dll so I can use it to create this aggregate function in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these [Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878119.aspx), they describe how to create StringUtilites.dll

You need 4 first steps of this instruction :

1. Open a Visual Studio or .NET Framework command prompt.
2. If necessary, create a directory for your sample. For this example, we will use C:\MySample.
   In c:\MySample, create StringUtils.vb (for the Visual Basic sample) or StringUtils.cs (for the C# sample) and copy the appropriate Visual Basic or C# sample code (below) into the file.
3. Compile the sample code from the command line prompt by executing one of the following, depending on your choice of language.

   - Vbc /target:library /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\System.Core.dll",C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll,C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll /debug- /target:library StringUtils.vb
   - Csc/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Data.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll /reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.XML.dll /target:library StringUtils.cs

Comment: It mentions "The AdventureWorks database must be installed on the SQL Server instance you are using" I realy have to install this database? How do I do this? It seems like I should just be able to get this dll without installing a new database?

Comment: Check my edited answer. No, in your case you no need to install the AdventureWorks DB

Comment: great! that worked. I have the StringUtil.dll file now. So I have to put it out on my database server, correct? Is there a standard place to put these type of things?